# Как прижать навбар вниз главного экрана

Tags: html, css3, bootstrap

Но при прокрутки вниз оставался фиксированным наверху ,скиньте примеры простые

Comment: Bootstrap? Или другой фреймворк?

Comment: Использываю Bootstrap3,

Comment: Если ответ верный, отметьте его

Answer (score 1):

[Источник](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar-fixed-bottom)

Да фиксации navbar вверху нужно добавить клас navbar-fixed-top

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        ...
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Да фиксации navbar внизу нужно добавить клас navbar-fixed-bottom

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</nav>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>
    <style>
    body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.starter-template {
  padding: 40px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Пример был взят от сюда https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_bottom_nav.asp

```css
body {margin:0;}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}

.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h1>Bottom Navigation Bar</h1>
  <p>Some text some text some text.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```